# I need a good, easy to use open source TTS

Tags: text-to-speech

I'm trying to find a relatively easy to use non-robotic sounding TTS since im not really familiar with python or TTS engine's in general so it's hard for me to just yoink one of those neural network TTS thingies from github and make it work on my machine.

So far i've installed coqui TTS(formerly Mozilla TTS as i understand) and its exactly what i need, however it doesnt work properly for some reason.

When im trying to feed it a sentence that is longer than half of a dozen words it might skip some words or might just stop mid sentence and while its running it has this error:

```
> Decoder stopped with `max_decoder_steps` 500
```

So its either:

a). What am i doing wrong with coqui and how do i make it read at least a paragraph of text or how do i fix this error?

or

b). Is there any other easy to use TTS programs that are similar in quality to coqui?

Comment: "Good" is relative. In my experience all open source TTS are barely tolerable.